# Reading full string c++

Tags: c++

If I have:

```
String a;
cin >> a;
cout << a << endl;
```

What is the easiest way to have it read the full string including spaces.

Comment: Use std::getline. And read a good C++  text book.

Comment: What if "the full string" contains a line-break? What determines the length or delimiter of a string?

Comment: Could you show me in an example please.  I don't know where to use that

Comment: Well I just mean a full entry of a string,  however long it needs to be

Comment: std::string expands, limited only by system memory.  What is your definition for "full string"  (if not 0 or more characters terminated by a '\n')?  Perhaps you are asking about binary files?  Please clarify.

Comment: When does a string end? How does it know the user has stopped typing and will never type again? There must be some exit condition. When you are posed with a function with which you are unfamiliar, [one of the best places to look is cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/). [Behind that is CPlusPlus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/). cppreference aims for literal correctness (as you may have found, close ain't that useful in programming). CPlusPlus seems to try to get the explanations a bit more readable, and as a result is sometimes wrong.

Answer (score -1):

This is actually basic c++ coding. I think this is what you're after. Also, there are quite a few good c++ books out there that are decent priced. Don't forget to #include

```
void newLine()
{
   char nextChar;
   do
   {
      cin.get(nextChar);
   } while (nextChar != '\n');
}
```